# Generate Array of Random Numbers with Specified Standard Deviation and Mean

Tags: arrays, matlab, random, mean, standard-deviation

I would like to create an `N` by `1` array of doubles where `N` is any integer value. Each value in the array should deviate from a nominal value `n` using a standard deviation of `n/10` and mean of `0`. `n` can be any integer or double value.

Is there a way to do this in MATLAB using `randn()` with the mean and standard deviation as input parameters?

Comment: You're already mentioning `randn`. Did you read its documentation? There's no need to loop.

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you want to use the specified mean and std-dev as parameters to a normal, you can use `randn` as pointed out by @CrisLuengo. However, if you want those values to be the specific sample statistics for your vector of data, you’ll have to do some conditioning or shifting and rescaling to yield those results.

Comment: @pjs. Your first statement is what I am looking for.

Comment: @JonathanFrutschy Please put that in your question then. Questions are supposed to be self-contained. Comments are considered transient, so clarifications shouldn't reside in comments.

Comment: @pjs Got it. I will keep this in mind moving forward.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yeah. I should have read the documentation more closely for randn()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this should solve your problem:

```
N = 10; 
n = 5;
standard_deviation = n / 10;

% Generates a vector of N ones, then moltiply it to the scalar n
nominal_values = n * ones(N, 1);

% Generates a vector of N standard random normal realizations, then multiply them to the scalar (n/10) -> you get a centered random normal with std n/10
deviations = standard_deviation * randn(N, 1);

% Get the final result
result_array = nominal_values + deviations;
```

I hope this will solve your problem, you are welcome to ask for a clarification if needed.

Comment: You can leave out `* ones(N, 1)`. It's just as easy to multiply `n` by an array of ones as it is to add `n` to an array of random numbers.

Comment: @CrisLuengo you are right! Probably what I did is clearer for someone who has a mathematical background and lacks of programming knowledge since is not defined the sum between a scalar and a vector from a mathematical point of view.